# gtsummary table: replace empty cell information with -

Tags: r, gtsummary

I'm using the package [gtsummary](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gtsummary/index.html) to create a table and I would like to replace the value in empty cells with "-" instead of "0 (0%)".

Is this possible?

an example of the table I am getting can be seen here:

```
library(gtsummary)

data <- data.frame(letter = c(rep("a", times = 3), rep("b", times = 3)),
                   value = c(rep(1, times = 3), rep(2, times = 3)))

data %>% tbl_summary(by = value)
```

Kind regards
Mathias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can manually manipulate the result, although I think this may be less ideal. I renamed `data` to `df` to avoid conflicts with the `data` function.

```
 library(dplyr) #probably not necessary since gtsummary uses tibble anyway
    df %>% tbl_summary(by = value) -> res
    
    res[1]$table_body <-res[1]$table_body %>% 
      mutate(across(c(stat_1, stat_2), ~gsub("^0.*", "-",.)))
    res
```

[image]

Comment: This was exactly was I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method using the built-in `gtsummary` function:

```
library(gtsummary)

data %>%
  gtsummary::tbl_summary(by = value) %>% 
  gtsummary::modify_table_body(
    ~.x %>%
      mutate(
        across(all_stat_cols(), ~gsub("^0.*", "-", .))
      )
  )
```